# How to draw $(A,B)\sim (C,D) \implies (A,C)\sim (B,D)$ when $A,B,C,D$ are collinears?

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

$(A,B)$ and $(C,D)$ are parallel vectors, in the book I'm reading, it illustrates one case for this proposition: $(A,B)\sim (C,D) \implies (A,C)\sim (B,D)$ with the following figure:

[image]

And then there's an exercise asking me to draw that proposition in the case that $A,B,C,D$ are collinear. I'm not sure about the answer but I guess that to achieve that, I should think of null vectors. The only possibility I see to achieve collinearity between all them is to think of $A=B=C=D$. Is this the answer?

**Edit:** I guess this is a viable answer:

[image]

The vector $(A,B)$ approach to $(C,D)$ until one is over the other.

Comment: What are you talking about?

Comment: Is it better now?

Comment: Excuse the holes in my education, but what does ~ mean?

Comment: @copper.hat $\sim$ means *similar*. About the holes on your education, there are only two reasons to be here: 1 - Filling these holes with knowing; 2 - Help others to do so.

Comment: What other rules are satisfied? Is $(A,B)+(B,D) \sim (A,D)$?

Comment: Nope, look the question [here](https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/1Hbnfhz2y9Og1DVdlwWVXrV0ms0AxR7CLJcrRWsGWMYw/edit) (in portuguese, but there are lots of cognates, you may be able to figure out.)

Comment: Hmm, the picture doesn't really add any information. You need to say what the rules for $\sim$ are to do anything...

Comment: The rules are the common equivalence relation rules. I guess.

Comment: The book I'm reading shows [these rules.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_relation#Definition)

Comment: I understand what an equivalence relation is, but without knowing what the relation is I cannot help.

Comment: Same to me, the book provided me only this information - but I'm almost sure about the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so correct me if I'm wrong, but I assume by collinear that just means points A, B, C, and D all fall on the same line.

So, assume they all fall on a straight line:

[image]

Suppose vector AB is magnitude +3, similar to CD.  Then suppose on the line A,B,C, and D fall on there's X magnitude between BC.  It follows that AC is 3+X and BD is 3+X, hence AC~BD?

---

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collinear):

> In geometry, collinearity is a property of a set of points, specifically, the property of lying on a single line.

In other words, a bunch of points that fall on the same line, e.g. are aligned:

[image]

Now if A, B, C, and D are collinear (as above), and the distance (magnitude) of $\overrightarrow {AB}$ is the same (~) as $\overrightarrow {CD}$  then you can see, visually that it follows that $\overrightarrow {AC}$ ~ $\overrightarrow {BD}$

Comment: Trying to understand. Did you see the edit in my post?

Comment: But shouldn't you draw a case in which $A,B,C,D$ are collinear? Is this the case?

Comment: I added more info.